# Create custom map for tracks with variables

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking to create a Google map with a search function like this:

http://www.mapmyrun.com/routes/

So, I would add time, length, incline of tracks, have a search function at the top, and the map needs to filter out, as well as show a list at the bottom

I am yet to hire people to do this, but did not find any approach, so do not know where to look.

Does someone know how this map was made (does Google have an API for such a thing, does it involve complex coding..) so I would have an idea what I am dealing with?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, Google provides APIs for everything. The website you had mentioned has plotted series of lat,long points on a track using maps API. Google allows limited number of points only on its free usage plan. Essentially if you are planning to plot many tracks such as the site you had mentioned you need to get license for Google Maps API. Yes, also it takes significant amount of Javascript & Map domain knowledge to build this kind of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That app (or website) you've linked is not relying on Google Maps API v3 to get the running tracks. What they've done instead is build their own track database where each record has attributes like

- Name
- Length
- Time
- Position

and a webUI to interactively filter those track records depending on their attributes.

The resulting set of tracks that match the conditions are then printed on a Google Maps Api v3 instance using markers and infowindow.

To accomplish the same functionality you would need to complete at least:

- The gathering and organization of your track data. Some will have to fill a  spreadsheet beforehand and decide on the relevant set of attributes that are worth mantaining.
- Where to store those results, because the storage engine should support filtering by position. PostgreSQL (using the [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) plugin)  and [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-a-2dsphere-index/) are good candidates for geosearches. MySQL does implement   basic geo functions too (albeit it doesn't scale too well when dealing with several thousand points)
- Which filters to offer, using which controls
- What backend to receive and process those filters, and deliver the matching results
- What mapping library to use to visualize those matching results

As you see, the only part when you use Google Maps Api v3 is the last one, and the limited set of functionalities you need for this project makes me think that, if there's any chance you'll surpass the free tier (in terms of request per hour or per day) you'll be better off with a simpler, free alternative like [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/).